# How to revalidate files in ng-file-upload?

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I use ng-file-upload in AngularJS to upload multiple files. I validate and upload files on form submit. When some files is invalid (for example maxSize exceeded) the user have possibility to remove file (I remove this file from files to upload array).

Unfortunately form.$error don't clear. How to revalidate form (files array)?

Thank for your time.

Comment: see https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1000

Comment: Basically if you remove the file by splice it doesn't trigger the $watch or model change chain. You need to change the actual object value of the file model which means copying/cloning the file array.

Comment: Yes it's works. Thanks.